# using tsql split row into multiple rows

Tags: t-sql

I am looking to write a script that will change Table 1 into Table 2.

**Table 1**

AccountNo    Name                      other field

```
   1      Mr T and Mrs M Lambert      xxx
```

I need to rewrite this as

**Table 2**

AccountNo      split       Name          other field

```
   1       a          Mr T Lambert             xxx
   1       b          Mrs M Lambert            xxx
```

Comment: Sorry your correct its over simplified

The name field is a free text field and could contain things like

McDonalds
Mr and Mrs Jones
Mr Smith
Mrs Peabody
Mr L Thomas & Mrs P Smith
A company Name
Jones and Smith

I need to split out where there are 2 people into one record each
but not for a company name like Jones and Smith which would be a company.
it may be a nightmare to do this but looking for any help I can get..........So far I have nothing.........still trying to get my head around it

Comment: My advice would be to hire a data cleansing firm to do it for you unless your table is small enough to do it by hand or the quality of the result isn't critical. How are you going to tell if you are really dealing with Mr T http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._T?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would take some scripting language of choice and write the converter with its aid. To me it looks like Perl or Ruby fit the task quite nicely.

For example, in Ruby this could be something like:

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('postgresql://localhost/db')
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

sql.begin_db_transaction

# fetch the data from the source table
sql.execute('SELECT * FROM source_table').each do |source_row|
  # source_row is a hash now of the following form:
  # { 'col_name_1' => 'col_value_1', 'col_name_2' => ... }

  # prepare transformed rows array that will result in the destination table
  transformed_rows = [ ]

  # make up all the transformed rows you need, based on the source fields
  transformed_rows << {
    'another_col_1' => source_row['col_name_1'],
    # ...
  }

  transformed_rows.each do |transformed_row|
    # generate and execute the insert statement for every transformed_row
    sql.execute("INSERT INTO destination_table(...) VALUES(...)")
  end
end

sql.commit_db_transaction
```

Undoubtedly it can be achieved in SQL, especially in richer dialects like PL/SQL, but text parsing (which you obviously will be doing quite a lot here) is not SQL's strong side. Therefore you will spend a lot of time figuring out string operations in a language that is not quite suited for them.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the from clause to your table name and it should work.

```
SELECT  AccountNo,
        person,
        other
FROM (VALUES(1,'Mr T and Mrs M Lambert','xxx')) AS yourTable (AccountNo,Name,Other)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Name),0,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(name))))) CA(lastName)
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(name,' and ','.'),1) person --first person
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(name,' and ','.'),2) + ' ' +  lastName --second person
             ) CA2
```

Results:

```
AccountNo   person                                                                                                                                                  other
----------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----
1           Mrs M Lambert                                                                                                                                           xxx
1           Mr T Lambert                                                                                                                                            xxx
```

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I have used Stephans comments to great effect.................it sent me on a path that may resolve my issues